# Wrap a link around image in slideshow using wordpress magic fields

Tags: php, wordpress, field

I have a slideshow set up with Magic fields like the code below, but 
now I need each image to have a seperate link. How can I set this up? 
I just can't think how I can add this to the code below, I appreciate 
any help anyone can offer me.

```
<div id="slider"> 
<?php 
    $images = getFieldOrder('slideshow_slide'); 
    if(is_array($images)){ 
        foreach($images as $image){ 
            echo get_image('slideshow_slide',1,$image); 
        } 
    } 
?> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooray MagicFields! <3

There are two ways to get an image in MagicFields.

Method 1 will return a full image tag:

```
echo get_image('slideshow_slide');
```

Method 2 just returns the url of the image:

```
echo get_image('slideshow_slide',1,1,0);
```

In order to generate a link to your full-size image, you'll need to construct an anchor tag using the second method. Maybe something like this:

```
$image_path = get_image('slideshow_slide',1,1,0);
```

`echo '<a href="' . $image_path . '">Insert link text or thumbnail here</a>';`

You might need to modify the above to work with your `foreach` loop, but that's the basic idea.

**Update:**
Here's what you need to do. Create another duplicateable text field, called image_url. This field will hold the link for your image. Each image will need a corresponding url. This loop should do what you want:

`if(is_array($images)){ 
  foreach($images as $image){ 
    $image_url = get('image_url',1,$image);
    echo "<a href='" . $image_url ."'>" . get_image('slideshow_slide',1,$image) . "</a>";
  } 
}`

Comment: Its not a link to a full size image I need, but to a page. So I need to add another field per image that will allow me to input a link, and wrap around the image. e.g <a href="link to another page">slideshowimage</a>

Comment: Oh, assuming it's a text field added via MagicFields (let's call it page_url), modify the above to be: `$image_path = get('page_url');`

Comment: So would it be: `<div id="slider"> 
<?php 
    $images = getFieldOrder('slideshow_slide'); 
    if(is_array($images)){ 
        foreach($images as $image){ 
            $image_path = get_image('slideshow_slide',1,1,0);
echo '<a href="' . $image_path = get('page_url');. '">
echo get_image('slideshow_slide',1,$image); </a>';
        } 
    } 
?> 
</div>`

Comment: Not exactly...I edited my answer with a new loop that should work.

Comment: So by creating a group called slides (and making it duplicate)
and within group creating an image field called slide and a text field called link this worked for the first image, but subsequent ones don’t show in the source.

Code:

`<?php 
$images = getFieldOrder('slide_slide'); 
if(is_array($images)){ foreach($images as $image){ $image_url = get('slide_link',1,$image); echo "<a href='" . $image_url ."'>" . get_image('slide_slide',1,$image) . "</a>"; } }
 ?>`

Comment: I thought by changing it to `<?php $images = getGroupOrder('slide_slide'); ` it might work but only showing the first slide

Comment: Still not had any luck showing any more than the first image. Can anyone help?

Comment: It was staring me in the face - it is the group I wanted to duplicate not the individual field - `<?php 
$images = getGroupOrder('slide_slide');
  foreach($images as $image){ 
  $image_url = get('slide_link',$image); echo "<a href='" . $image_url ."'>" . get_image('slide_slide',$image) . "</a>"; 
  } 
 ?>`

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I guess in the future I shouldn't make as many assumptions about what is going on, and just ask for clarification (link to page, not full image...duplicate-able groups vs. fields, etc...)